# Getting memory allocation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to find out the optimum vertex cover of a graph using brute force technique, but it works for smaller graphs like of vertex count 20 but for vertex count > 50 it prompts bad_alloc() error. I am unable to find where it is causing the memory unable to allocate. I'm trying both version to find all subsets both recursively as well as sequentially.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<queue>
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void subsetR(bool **,bool *,int); //optimum vertex cover
void subsetS(bool **g,int len);
void printArray(bool *, int);
bool checkVertexCover(bool **,bool *);
bool checkVertexCover(bool **g,const vector<bool>&ss);
void printGraph(bool **,int);
int sizeOfArray(bool *,int vertexCount);
int sizeOfArray(vector<bool>&ar,int vertexCount);
int approxVertexCover(bool **,int);
int approxVertexCover2(bool **, int);
int findMaxDegree(bool **,int);
bool isGraphEmpty(bool **,int);
void initializeAr(bool *subset,int len);
bool eq(bool*a,bool*b);

int mini = 1111;
int vertexCount = 0;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Vertex Cover Problem"<<endl;
    ifstream myfile;
    //cout<<"Enter the graph file name"<<endl;
    //char fileName[20];
    //cin>>fileName;
    myfile.open("chordal_graphs.txt");
    //myfile.open("g.txt");

    int graphNo = 0;
    bool **graph = NULL;
    bool *vertices = NULL;

    srand(time(NULL));

    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile >> graphNo;
        cout<<"No of graphs: "<<graphNo<<endl;
        for(int s=0;s<graphNo;s++)
        {
            cout<<"\nGraph: "<<s+1<<endl;
            myfile >> vertexCount;
            graph = new bool*[vertexCount];
            vertices = new bool[vertexCount];
            for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
            {
                vertices[i] = false;
                graph[i] = new bool[vertexCount];
            }

            for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
                    myfile >> graph[i][j];

            //cout<<"before calling"<<endl;
            //printGraph(graph,vertexCount);
            //subsetR(graph,vertices,0);
            cout<<"Min vertex-cover size = "<<mini<<endl;


            int vc = approxVertexCover(graph,vertexCount);
            cout<<"General Approx vertex cover: "<<vc<<endl;
            //cout<<"Approximation Ratio: "<<static_cast<float>(vc)/static_cast<float>(mini)<<endl;

            vc = approxVertexCover2(graph,vertexCount);
            cout<<"Greedy Approx vertex cover: "<<vc<<endl;
            //cout<<"Approximation Ratio: "<<static_cast<float>(vc)/static_cast<float>(mini)<<endl;

            mini = 1111;

            subsetS(graph,vertexCount);
            cout<<"Min vertex-cover size = "<<mini<<endl;
            mini = 1111;
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"Unable to open the file"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void subsetR(bool **g,bool *ar,int index)
{
    if(index < vertexCount)
    {
        if(index+1 == vertexCount)
        {
            //printArray(ar,vertexCount);
            if(checkVertexCover(g,ar) == true)
            {
                int sz = sizeOfArray(ar,vertexCount);
                if(sz < mini)
                    mini = sz;
            }
        }
        subsetR(g,ar,index+1);

        ar[index] = true;
        for(int i=index+1;i<vertexCount;i++)
            ar[i] = false;
        if(index+1 == vertexCount)
        {
            //printArray(ar,vertexCount);
            if(checkVertexCover(g,ar) == true)
            {
                int sz = sizeOfArray(ar,vertexCount);
                if(sz < mini)
                    mini = sz;
            }
        }
        subsetR(g,ar,index+1);
    }
}

void subsetS(bool **g,int len)
{
    unsigned long long n = pow(2,len);
    //generatePrintBinary(n);
    //cout<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
    vector<bool> b;
    b.clear();
    b.resize(len,false);

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        //for(int k=0;k<len;k++)
            //cout<<b[k];
        //cout<<"\n";
        if(checkVertexCover(g,b) == true)
        {
            int sz = sizeOfArray(b,len);
            if(sz < mini)
            {
                mini = sz;
                //cout<<"mini 00 "<<mini<<endl;
            }
        }
        for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(b[i] == 0)
            {
                b[i] = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
                b[i] = 0;
        }
    }

}


void printArray(bool *ar,int vertexCount)
{
    cout<<"Array is :"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        cout<<ar[i]<<" ";

    cout<<"\n";
}

bool checkVertexCover(bool **g,bool *ss)
{
    //printArray(ss,vertexCount);
    //cout<<"check"<<endl;

    bool **graph = NULL;
    graph = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        graph[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            graph[i][j] = g[i][j];

    //printGraph(g,vertexCount);

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        if(ss[i] == true)
        {
            //cout<<"i "<<i<<endl;
            for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            {
                graph[i][j] = false;
                graph[j][i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //cout<<"after"<<endl;
    //printGraph(graph,vertexCount);

    return isGraphEmpty(graph,vertexCount);
}

bool checkVertexCover(bool **g,const vector<bool>& ss)
{
    //printArray(ss,vertexCount);
    //cout<<"check"<<endl;

    bool **graph = NULL;
    graph = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        graph[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            graph[i][j] = g[i][j];

    //printGraph(g,vertexCount);

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        if(ss.at(i) == true)
        {
            //cout<<"i "<<i<<endl;
            for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            {
                graph[i][j] = false;
                graph[j][i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    //cout<<"after"<<endl;
    //printGraph(graph,vertexCount);

    return isGraphEmpty(graph,vertexCount);
}

void printGraph(bool **g,int vertexCount)
{
    cout<<"Graph is: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
        {
            cout<<g[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

int sizeOfArray(bool *ar,int vertexCount)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i] == true)
            result++;
    }
    return result;
}

int sizeOfArray(vector<bool>&ar,int vertexCount)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        if(ar.at(i) == true)
            result++;
    }
    return result;
}

int approxVertexCover(bool **g,int vertexCount)
{
    bool **graph = NULL;
    graph = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        graph[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            graph[i][j] = g[i][j];

    int result = 0;
    int sz = vertexCount*vertexCount;
    bool graphEmpty = false;

    //cout<<"before while"<<endl;

    while(graphEmpty == false)
    {
        //cout<<"hello"<<endl;
        graphEmpty = true;

        int randomEdge = rand() % sz;
        //cout<<"after randome"<<endl;
        if(graph[randomEdge/vertexCount][randomEdge%vertexCount] == false)
            while(graph[randomEdge/vertexCount][randomEdge%vertexCount] == false)
                randomEdge = rand() % sz;

        int v1 = randomEdge/vertexCount;
        int v2 = randomEdge%vertexCount;
        //cout<<randomEdge<<endl;
        //cout<<"v1: "<<v1<<" v2: "<<v2<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        {
            graph[v1][i] = false;
            graph[i][v1] = false;

            graph[v2][i] = false;
            graph[i][v2] = false;
        }

        //printGraph(g,vertexCount);

        result = result + 2;

        graphEmpty = isGraphEmpty(graph,vertexCount);
    }
    return result;
}

bool isGraphEmpty(bool **g,int vertexCount)
{
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
        {
            if(g[i][j] == true)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int approxVertexCover2(bool **g, int vertexCount)
{
    int result = 0;
    bool graphEmpty = isGraphEmpty(g,vertexCount);

    bool **graph = NULL;
    graph = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        graph[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
            graph[i][j] = g[i][j];

    while(graphEmpty == false)
    {
        int v = findMaxDegree(graph,vertexCount);
        result++;
        for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        {
            graph[v][i] = false;
            graph[i][v] = false;
        }
        graphEmpty = isGraphEmpty(graph,vertexCount);
    }
    return result;
}

int findMaxDegree(bool **g,int vertexCount)
{
    int degree = 0;
    int maxi = -1111;
    int resultVertex = -1;

    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
    {
        degree = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<vertexCount;j++)
        {
            if(g[i][j] == true)
                degree++;
        }
        if(maxi < degree)
        {
            maxi = degree;
            resultVertex = i;
        }
    }
    return resultVertex;
}

void initializeAr(bool *subset,int len)
{
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        subset[i] = false;
}

bool eq(bool *a,bool *b)
{
    for(int i=0;i<vertexCount;i++)
        if(a[i] != b[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger to step through the code line-by-line until you learn where it blows up.

Comment: No idea how to reproduce the behavior without input data. At least I'm missing the delete[] statements for the corresponding new[].

Comment: I'm curious; why do you have a double pointer of booleans? A bool is a bit. Unless that's your intention, I would have to cast doubts as to the necessity in using pointer to booleans.

Comment: Guys, I got it, somewhere it was going out of bounds, @Poriferous well practically bool data type seems 1 bit, but in the compilers it's of 4 bit, don't exactly why, but it is like that only. But I got by changing the 2d pointer to vector...Thanx